# Convert Fingerprint-Bitmap to ISO/IEC 19794-2 template

Tags: bitmap, raspberry-pi, fingerprint, data-conversion

I need to convert bitmaps files with fingerprints to ISO/IEC 19794-2 templates. The source images have a resolution of 320x480 pixels.

Currently i use [SourceAFIS](https://sourceafis.angeloflogic.com/) (.Net library) for this task. It requires about 1-3 seconds on the RaspberryPi to do this job. The tool runs as service which means i do not always restart it. My current usecase requires (soft-)realtime and everything runs very fast, except for this conversion.

I don't know if this conversion is just very expensive or if the algorithm is not optimal implemented. It works very well, but it is just a bit slow.

Maybe someone else knows a very fast and simple command line tool which does exactly convert bitmap files to ISO/IEC 19794-2 templates?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

National Institute of Standards and
Technology (NIST) have  BiomDI, opensource tools for fingerprint operations in C:
http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/biomdi.cfm

There's a mirror on github:
https://github.com/tarzan0820/BIOMDI

Comment: Thanks for the link:)

Comment: @KevinMeier Were you able to convert images to templates using BiomDI? I am trying to convert fingerprint images to ANSI or ISO 19794-2 template format but cannot find appropriate BiomDI package for this task.

Comment: @LaurentY, do you have any idea to convert fingerprint images to ISO/ANSI templates using BiomDI or other tool? I am trying to achieve this task in Android.

Comment: hi guys any luck Im looking for the same